# Sending a message in a specific channel - not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js 12, and I've tried the following:

```
client.channels.cache.find(x => x.id == "id").send('message')

client.channels.cache.find(x => x.name == "channel-name").send('message')

...and...

client.channels.cache.get('id').send('message')
```

and all of them return an error saying 'cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Now, I know that usually means that the ID of the channel is wrong. However, I've copied it and repasted it like five times. It's the right ID, I assure you.

I've been using this system for months, and now it won't work.

Note: I have the following defined in the file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You are either not caching the channel, or it doesn’t exist. I can’t help you if it doesn’t exist. It is returning undefined because it doesn’t see it in the cache. You can easily cache the channels by using a simple `fetch()` method.

```js
await client.channels.fetch();
client.channels.cache.get(…).send(…)
```

You can also directly fetch the channel using the API

```js
(await client.channels.fetch('id')).send(…)
```

If you are getting an error that says await is only valid in async functions, change the listener to look like this:

```js
client.on(event, async (variable) => {
//code here
//notice it says 'async' before 'variable'
})
//'event' can be any event, variable is the object provided (message events provide message objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const channel = await client.channels.fetch(<id>);

await channel.send('hi')
```

This should work.

You can also try this

```
client.channels.fetch(channelID).then(channel => {
  channel.send("hi");
});
```

Comment: wouldnt that just send the channel itself and throw an error lol? like how do i send a message to the channel w this?

Comment: Oh sorry it's late I didn't read it right. I edited it

Comment: oh well, in that case, that didnt work for me either lol

Comment: its also throwing an error about using await outside of an async function.

Comment: Look on top and try the new one @AndenWieseler