# I'm trying to make my bot send messages to a specific channel by using channel id

Tags: discord.js

This is the code i used:

```
bot.on("message", function (message) {
              if (message.content == '.shift') {
                const channel01 = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "ChannelIDhere")
               channel01.send('Text');
    }
    });
```

However it doesn't work for me, Most likely it is **Outdated**, after all the reference i found is a year ago, or i simply made a **mistake**.

Edit:

```
client.on('msg', msg => {
  if (msg.content === '.go') {
    const channel01 = client.channels.cache.get("872654795364765756");
   channel01.send('Text');
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a message in a specific channel - not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493054/sending-a-message-in-a-specific-channel-not-working)

Comment: You can use `bot.channels.cache.get("channelIDhere");`, if it doesn't return anything, then the channel doesn't exist, or your bot can't access it.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox, I changed my code in the question above, is the changes all correct?

Comment: Hmm, I assumed your `bot` is the client, but it seems like you've already got the `client` set as `client`. so you should replace it as `client.channels.cache.get("channelIDhere");`.

Comment: @PerplexingParadox, I changed it, Thank You!